# Password notification visible on my mac screen

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a strange thing that happened on my mac book pro and the screenshot is attached. I think this will appear when I connect my additional desktop screen to mac.IT will not close even if it is a clickable button.

Can anyone help to remove this and find what is the reason behind this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and hold down the command key and then left-click on it. Alternatively, try click on it and use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>

I found [this post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252140746) talking about the exact same thing. Also [this one](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252109550). They go into a bit more detail about checking accessibility features and keychain (mobile mouse server).